# Does .net create any temporary C# files when uses manage wrappers to unmanage C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

Usually when we need to use native C++ DLL in C# program, write a manage wrapper is the way to achieve it. 
Inside such program, If I press F12 (go to function definition) on a DLL function call, It goes to a C# file that looks like having all the functions forward declarations. I check the location of this file and it exist in the windows temp directory.

So my question is , When we uses a C++ unmanage DLL by manage wrapper in a C# program, Does .NET framework ( or any other component) create any temporary C# classes relevant to interface classes in the DLL?

Comment: No, but it creates a temporary file with their definition when you want to browse them...

Answer (score 1):

There are no "temporary C# files".  If you use `Go to Definition` and the IDE only has an assembly reference for the definition then it doesn't have a shot at finding the source code file for the definition.  So it *auto-generates* one from the metadata in the reference assembly.  That looks fairly similar to a source code file, but of course without any comments and without the code for the classes.  It cannot be compiled.  It is also in C#, even if the original assembly was created from C++/CLI or VB.NET code.

Nice feature, but don't confuse it for anything more than it is.  If you want the IDE to take you to the actual source code file then you need a project reference, not an assembly reference, for the library.